# Vim Plugins not working when not in Home directory

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

When I run `vim` in my home directory, everything works perfectly with all plugins working right. However, whenever I run `vim` in any other directory, for example on in my desktop directory the plugins have problem [In this case, the NerdTree plugin, it says:]

```
Error detected while processing VimEnter Autocommands for "*":
E492: Not an editor command: NERDTree
```

Comment: Can we see any nerdtree mappings you have in your vimrc?

Comment: Check for any relative filespecs (e.g. `.vim` instead of `~/.vim`) in `:set runtimepath?`